# Update stackexchange.com/sites to add Twitter links to recently created Twitter accounts

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, twitter

If you go to https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#oldest, you can see a list of sites and Twitter links for the ones that have Twitter accounts.

[image: twitter links]

However, some time ago ([last year](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299934/how-did-stack-overflow-get-its-twitter-account)), Stack Overflow got a [Twitter account](https://twitter.com/StackOverflow), but the SE page was not updated to add its reference. The same (minor) issue may happen for other sites. Another example: [Spanish Stack Overflow](https://twitter.com/esStackOverflow).

Comment: I think the @StackOverflow Twitter account is a special case... But the rest are automatic, and I think the links were automatically added. (For instance, the link to  Stack Overflow en español's Twitter account does appear there now.) That said, as stated in the answer to [Are the various site Tweetbots affected by the upcoming Twitter API changes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/386451/335251), those site-specific tweetbots are being shut down.

Comment: Anyway... Given that they're being shut down, I'm not sure what should be done with this bug report. Is the issue still occurring, or should this be closed as no longer reproducible?