# Any chance of adding a way to follow feeds using ActivityPub?

Tags: feature-request, feed

It would be nice to have an equivalent to the site Twitter feeds (for those sites which still have Twitter feeds, and equivalents for those which don’t) accessible over ActivityPub in a way I could follow from my Mastodon account. Many implementations of ActivityPub are Open Source, so in principle it wouldn’t be *too* much work to implement.

And other feeds could also be added, such as `@387056@meta.stackexchange.com` to follow a specific question, perhaps.

`@hot.questions@meta.stackexchange.com`

Comment: FWIW, the [Twitter bots have been retired](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/386476/295232). Given their low effectiveness, I doubt the company is willing to spend time developing a Mastodon integration, but let's see ...

Comment: What's wrong with rss? 

Comment: Is there actually an RSS/Atom equivalent of the old Twitter posts, @JourneymanGeek?

Comment: hm.. apparently not, but it feels like a more platform agnostic base to build off

Comment: There are also already apps for converting feeds to ActivityPub, too. So it could be a good option to build on. @JourneymanGeek